# Foreach loop PHP T_FOREACH Error

Tags: php

I know this is an error staring me blank in the face but for the life of me i cannot see it. any idea why? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
$locations = Select('SELECT location_id, venue_city FROM location');

echo '<select style="width:100px;">' .
        foreach($locations as $location)
        { . '<option value="' .  $location['location_id'] .'">'. $location['venue_city'] . '</option>' . } .
     '</select>';
```

Comment: actually .. whats `Select()` do ?? its not a core php function

Comment: You can't have a foreach loop inside a concatenation. You may want to look at `.=` concatenating inside the foreach loop, not the other way around.

Comment: 'Select()' is a function from a library, it does all the connection to database for you. that way every time you make a new page you don't have to copy in connection strings and stuff. Also noted for the '.='

Comment: well for the next question remember we don't know what libraries you are using.

Answer (score -2):

Foreach only accepts array values. I believe you are calling it with a string value.

Comment: do you know that the `Select` function returns?